# How would one find the number of files with a particular suffix in a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the need to search a directory and display the number of text (*.txt) files.  In researching, I am fairly certain I can use glob and os, but am at a bit of a loss on how to even start.

Comment: Start to learn Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.listdir`

```
import os
txtFiles = 0
for file in os.listdir("/dir"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        txtFiles +=1
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

I would try something along the lines of this:

```
import glob
import os

def fileCount():
    myFiles = dict()
    directory = "C:\somefolder\someotherfolder"

    for file in glob.glob("*"):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
            myFiles[extension] = myFiles.get(extension, 0) + 1
            print(os.getcwd())
            os.chdir(directory)
            print('after chdir', os.getcwd())

    return myFiles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = fileCount()
    print(files)
```

The line `for file in glob.glob("*"):` will read all files in the specified directory.
The line `name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)` will split out the file name and the extension into two objects, but only if the object is a file (as opposed to another folder).

Hope this helps